# Cepstrum of finite impulse train

Tags: matlab, speech-processing, cepstral-analysis

In Acero's *Spoken language processing* (p. 309) it says that the cepstrum of a finite length impulse train
$$x[n] = \sum^{M-1}_{k=0} \delta[n-kN]$$
is given by
$$\hat{x}[n] = \sum^{ \infty}_{r=1} \frac{\delta[n-rN]}{r} - \sum^{\infty}_{l=1} \frac{\delta[n-lMN]}{l} $$

from where is clear that the cepstrum should be non-zero only for values of $n$ that are multiples of $N$.

I'm trying to visualise this result with a quick matlab script ($N =5$ and $M =3$):

```
delta_train = [1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1];
stem(cceps(delta_train));
```

but it gives by result

[image]

that is inconsistent with the above expression because it's non-zero for every $n$.

I was thinking that this may be somehow related to the way matlab implements *cceps()* with the FFT and the fact that the computed cesptrum is actually an aliased version of $\hat{x}[n]$, nevertheless, it should still be zero-valued for those $n$.

Comment: Try adding 4 more zeros to the end of you impulse train.  Then explain why the result cepstrum differs.

Comment: @hotpaw2 I can see it know. In that case the cepstrum is aliased in a way it does not converge. I can get the result I want with a good amount of zero-padding so the aliased versions don't affect. thanks!